# How to send the entire contents of a listbox to SQL database?

Tags: vb.net

For a listbox loading txt file and now I want to send the contents to sql database in which there are two tables m.in user, comm
http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/8069892000_1409841532.png
How to do to add all items were recorded in the table at the same time with id user?
ex. http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/5048367700_1409841766.png

The following method works only when I select one item.

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection
         Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
         Try
             con.ConnectionString = "Server = x; User ID = x; Password = x; Database = x;"
             con.Open ()
             cmd.Connection = con
             cmd.CommandText = "insert into ycomm (user, comm) values ​​('" & ListView2.Items (0) .SubItems (0) .Text & "', '" & ListBox1.SelectedItem & "')"
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ()

         Catch ex As Exception

         Finally
             con.Close ()
         End Try
         Call showData ()
```

Comment: it only works when you have selected items because you are specifying `ListBox1.SelectedItem`, no surprise there.

Comment: i know but how to insert all items?

Comment: is that a trick question?  go thru all ListBox1.Items and insert them - you answered your own question

Comment: A suggestion, wrap your command and connections in a using statement to ensure they are released properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this but dees now work, where is problem?

Replace:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into ycomm (user, comm) values ​​('" _
& ListView2.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text & "', '" & ListBox1.SelectedItem & "')"
```

With

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ycomm (user, comm) VALUES(@user, @comm)"

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", ListView2.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@comm", SqlDbType.VarChar)

    For i As Integer = 0 To lst.Items.Count
        cmd.Parameters("@comm").Value = lst.Items(i).Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
```